# Why can't if and else statements be on separate lines in R

Tags: r, if-statement, indentation

Why is it that when using an if else statement in R, the "else" cannot be on a new line unless the whole statement is nested within another form of statement, loop or function?

For example, the below code does not work:

```
x <- 5

if(x<10){
  print("x<10")
}
else{
  print("x>9")
}
```

However if we put the whole thing within a loop so that it is indented, suddenly it works fine

```
for(i in 1:1){
  x <- 5
  
  if(x<10){
    print("x<10")
  }
  else{
    print("x>9")
  }
}
```

I understand that R wants you to write them like below:

```
x <- 5

if(x<10){
  print("x<10")
}else{
  print("x>9")
}
```

But I don't like how that looks and also want to understand why this syntax / style is only a requirement when the statement is not nested within something else.

Thanks!

Comment: I also don't know. But it also works if you put the statement between parenthesis `( )` instead of loop.

Comment: Looks fine, ever consulted an [R style guide](https://jef.works/R-style-guide/)?

Comment: Because the language "designers" thought that semicolons were not needed as statement-terminators. So Newline became a *kind of* statement terminator, instead of just some whitespace. Well, sometimes. (Python made the same choice)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with enforcing a style, but to do with how the R parser works. In essence, when your `if` clause is syntactically complete with a newline at the end of its closing bracket, the console thinks you are done with that instruction, and waits for its next instruction. But an `else` clause has to be part of the *same instruction*. If the *next* instruction starts with an `else`, the R parser doesn't know what the `else` is referring to.

Let's demonstrate this for clarity. If you paste the following code into the console:

```r
x <- 5

if(x<10){
print("x<10")
}
```

Then you will see this:

```r
> x <- 5
>   
> if(x<10){
+   print("x<10")
+ }
[1] "x<10"
>
```

Notice that if a line of code is syntactically complete, R will run the code, then print the console marker `>` at the start of the next line. If a newline symbol is present in the pasted code, but the code is syntactically incomplete, the console places a `+` at the start of each line, indicating that the R parser needs more input before it has syntactically complete code to run.

But if you run your example code, look what happens:

```r
> if(x<10){
+   print("x<10")
+ }
[1] "x<10"
> else{
Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"
>   print("x>9")
[1] "x>9"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Your `if` statement with its associated brackets was a syntactically complete element, so R ran the code. It printed out `[1] "x<10"` as expected, then waited for its next instruction. However, its next instruction was `else {`, and the R parser knows that *no* syntactically correct R code can *start* with an *else*. R can't go back in time and undo what it did in the `if` clause just because you *subsequently* write an `else` clause.

So, this has nothing to do with enforcing a style. You simply need a way of saying to R "I'm not done yet" after an `if` clause. There are various ways to do this. For example, your code would be fine inside a function, or a loop, or brackets. These are just ways of saying to the R parser : "don't run the code yet, I'm not done."

```r
x <- 5

{
  
if(x<10){
  print("x<10")
}
else{
  print("x>9")
}
  
}
#> [1] "x<10"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>